# Require and import showing different behaviors. Why is this so?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I was using both `require` and `import` but got some different behaviors from both. Until now I was assuming that `require` and `import` are just ES5 vs ES6. I was doing the below:

**abc.js**

```
console.log("abc");
```

**xyz.js**

```
console.log("xyz");
```

**hello.js**

```
require("./abc");
import "./xyz";
```

and the second time when I changed the file and swapped the two lines.

**hello.js**

```
import "./xyz";
require("./abc");
```

Both the times it was giving the same output

```
xyz
abc
```

ie. output of `require` was always after the import. If I use only import, or only `import`, it was giving consoles as expected ie. one after the other.
Can anyone help in understanding this?

Comment: Pretty certain `import` statements are hoisted, which would cause this behavior, but I don't have a source to confirm it as an answer.

Comment: I don't know why people just press any button without any comment. -1? For what?
@zzzzBov hoisted?????

Comment: interesting, how would a hoisted function change anything? Are you sure the interpreter doesn't just process import statements before it runs require statements? I think this is a legitimate question.

Comment: @shanimal processing import statements first is what "hoisted" means.

Comment: I never thought about hoisting that way. Thanks!

Comment: to clarify... it didn't seem that an import statement (that actually executes code) is considered "hoisted" in the same way `function foo()` is. I wonder how the es5 transpiler gets out of dealing with circular references in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Modules declared in `hello.js` via `import` are imported before any code in `hello.js` is run. It doesn't matter if the `import` statement appears after another statement. The module is still loaded before the code is run. So that is why you are getting "xyz" first no matter where you put the `import` statement.

`require()` on the other hand is programmatic. The module code is run when the `require()` statement is encountered while your program is running.

Answer (score 1):

Since ES6 modules yet to be implemented(not sure) in node.js, I'm assuming you're using babel for transpiling `export, import` statements.

When babel transpiling the code it always place the import statements at the top of the module, therefore this happens. You can test it in [REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/).

[DEMO](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&code=require('abc')%3B%0Aimport%20'xyz'%3B)

[More in depth details on `import` and `require`](https://hackernoon.com/node-js-tc-39-and-modules-a1118aecf95e#.ay89q0esw)